# MediaPlayerElement fullscreen button does not hide navigation bar

Tags: uwp

I added a `MediaPlayerElement` to my XAML as follow:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="EmbeddedPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
     <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
          <MediaTransportControls IsSkipBackwardButtonVisible="True" IsSkipBackwardEnabled="True" IsSkipForwardButtonVisible="True" IsSkipForwardEnabled="True"/>
      </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

The problem is that the Fullscreen button provided by `MediaTransportControls` does NOT hide the navigation bar (the region containing the back, start and search buttons) on phone while I expect it to, just like the system "Movies & TV" app. It only hides the status bar!? (It works on desktop.)

Is there a secret code to allow the navigation bar to be hidden or is it just not possible with 3rd party app? I tried [`ApplicationView.TryEnterFullScreenMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.tryenterfullscreenmode.aspx) in my `MainPage` on Windows 10 Mobile 14393.693 but just like above, the navigation bar is not hidden (only the status bar does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding my answer for [another problem on casting video to TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227789/cast-video-to-tv-using-mediaplayerelement/44260767#44260767), I found out that one MUST NOT use the recommended `MediaPlayerElement` but the deprecated `MediaElement` for the navigation bar to be hidden properly.

Answer (score 0):

The "Movie & TV" app doesn't hide the navigation bar by default. The reason for why you see it hide the navigation bar by default is that the player is in full window model by default. Double tapped the player of "Movie & TV" app, the player will exit the full window mode and the bar will show.

So if you want have same effects like "Movie & TV" app, you need to set the  [`IsFullWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement.isfullwindow) property of [`MediaPlayerElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement) like follows:

```
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="EmbeddedPlayer" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   IsDoubleTapEnabled="True" IsFullWindow="True" >
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls />
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

Also you can define a [`DoubleTapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.doubletapped) event for the `MediaPlayerElement` that double tap will exit the full window mode. Code as follows and now it has same effects as the "Movie & TV" done.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    EmbeddedPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/New2.mp4"));
    EmbeddedPlayer.DoubleTapped += EmbeddedPlayer_DoubleTapped; 
}

private void EmbeddedPlayer_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

    if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
        view.ExitFullScreenMode();
    else
        view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
}
```

Comment: Well, the question wasn't about hiding the navigation bar by default. I want the app to display normally (with command bar etc.) but when the user click on the "Fullscreen" button on the `MediaPlayerElement`, the status bar and navigation bar should be hidden. That's the expected behavior. But I guess such issue will never get fixed. The answer might require some combination of methods like `SetDesiredBoundsMode`, `SuppressSystemOverlays ` but there are just too many to try out.

Comment: By the way, I think the recommended way to full screen for media player is to use the `IsFullWindows` property instead of doing `TryEnterFullScreenMode`. That way other UI components will be hidden as well.

Comment: Of course, I did and it didn't work. Adding `IsFullWindow="true"` put the media player in full screen, hiding the status bar but the navigation bar is still there and it occludes part of the playing video. I also notice that this is the same for "Movies & TV" app when the video is paused: the navigation bar is only hidden when the video is playing.

Comment: @AnHoa, in that case, I cannot reproduce your issue on my side. Could you please tell what device you are testing on?

Comment: I did my testing on a Lumia 635 (the 512MB RAM version).

Comment: I finally found the solution.